# one condition in my .gitginore ist not being effective (while another is)

Tags: git, gitignore

I don't get this behaviour

```
git status
...
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   ansible.log
```

while

```
me@rhel8:~/repos/ansible_get_postgres_version> cat .gitignore 

ansible.log
*.log
*.out
```

so, apparently the .gitignore is not effective when in comes to the `ansible.log` file.

However, `.gitignore` is not completely ineffective

`echo "hello gitty" > test_this.out` creates such a file but that is **not** shown as new to git with a `git status` (so, it actually **is** ignored).

One condition I could imagine as being the culprid is the fact that maybe the `.gitignore` did not exist before the `ansible.log` file got created. It that is the case ... what would I have to do in order to get it to being ignored by git as intendet?

Comment: added `another.log` file which also is being ignored, so my suspicions seems to be correct. Leaves me with the question on how to getting the `ansible.log` file to being ignored as well.

Comment: `.gitignore` applies to *untracked* files; it is not intended to ignore changes to tracked files. `ansible.log` has already been added to your repository.

Answer (score 2):

What you could try is using `git rm --cached ansible.log` that way the file is removed from the repo (unversioned). As long as it is versioned, it will show up in `git status`

Comment: thx @Kevin ... what does _"versioned"_ precisely mean in this context?

Comment: @vrms I mean with that, that it is being tracked by git. So git will keep track of changes (versions) for that file. The proper term would have been "tracked" instead of versioned